# Aligning 3 dividers horozontally, only middle shows up?

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment, divider

Correct me if im wrong, isnt this supposed to display all three divs side by side? Only the supposed middle (now floated to the very left) div (with some content in) was displayed . the other were not displayed at all.

Thanks!

Edit*: I closed the 2nd div but it seems like as soon as i remove the content from the divs, they cease to appear. I put in a br in them and they now display a small br sized stripe, how to make it autonomous? (not needing the br?

HTML:

```
<div id="borderleft"><br></div>
<div id="bordermiddle"><br></div>
<div id="borderright"><br></div>
```

CSS:

```
#borderleft {
background-color: rgba(220, 220, 200, 0.8);
height:23%;
width:13%;
float:left;
}
#bordermiddle {
text-align:center;
background-color: rgba(220, 220, 200, 0.4);
width:74%;
height:100%;
float:left;
margin:0 0 10% 0;
}
#borderright {
background-color: rgba(220, 220, 200, 0.8);
height:23%;
width:13%;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Typo. Didn't close one <div>.

Comment: @Manfred Gibson Did you set you body and html `height:100%` en `width:100%` ? check my edit... in the answer en check my DEMO, cause it doens't have the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the second `<div>` like here:

```
<div id="borderleft"></div>
<div id="bordermiddle"></div>   <!---------- Close this one ---------->
<div id="borderright"></div>
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zjqLwdfj/1/)**

---

**Edit:**

Add this to your css : `html,body{width:100%; height:100%;margin:0;}`

Comment: I added and now its all fked up haha can you explain what the html width height margin does? I already had it set to that on body though.

Comment: Well, the `width:100%;` says that he can use all the width space, the same with height. You could leave the `margin:0;` this resets only al browser set margins.

Comment: Unfortunately the html {height:100%} seems to mess with the beautiful background bigtime. It leaves the background to seemingly original resolution, resulting in a blank area when scrolling down. My background is set as such: background-image:(imagelink);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: than to see what the problem could be, we need to see more relevant code.. because my answer is a solution to the code you gave us.. perhaps a link to the website?

Comment: I made a broken (100% height html) version http://project-smoothvillage.comeze.com/Project-Home-Broken.html and a non broken one, with height set to auto. http://project-smoothvillage.comeze.com/Project-Home.html The buttons dont seem to be working but whatever its a bad hosting site.

Comment: Im sorry. Cant help you with that.. Good luck

Comment: I'll just put it to auto then! thanx

Answer (score 0):

As long as the height of your divs are set in percentages they will always cease to appear when you remove the content.

If you want them to show on the page without any content you will have to set their height in pixels or ems.

Ben

Comment: But then it messes up the website on other resolutions?